# Is there a way in elasticsearch to sort records of array field?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Say I have records that have a field that is array of String 
with these values

```
1) [A,B] 
2) [D,E,A]
3) [D,A,B]
4) [A,B,C]
```

I would expect the docs/records to be sorted like

```
1) [A,B]
2) [A,B,C]
3) [D,A,B]
4) [D,E,A]
```

Comment: Yes use a script in the sort part.

Comment: using elasticsearch java libraries

Answer (score 0):

The first option would be to make sure that your indexing client does sort the array prior to indexing documents.

If that's not feasible, the second option would be to [update your documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) using a script that would properly sort the arrays:

```
POST your-index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "Collections.sort(ctx._source.array)"
  }
}
```

Comment: This would sort within the array field, I want the records to be sorted based on array values

Comment: Oh my, I guess I missed the point, sorry. Then go with what @LeBigCat suggested